# Solaris 10 system - used disc space keeps on increasing even after deleting the directory

Tags: process, solaris, deleted-files

I deleted a directory on slice `mmf` but it came back - the size is still same and also it keeps increasing. The reason for deleting the directory is that I couldn't find the process linked to creating logs on that directory.

It is now at 82% and keeps increasing every 2 hours.

Is there a way to identify the process and kill it? Can I reboot the box which will release the process creating those files?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to find the process that's writing to the unlinked (not deleted!) file(s). All the Unix and Unix-a-like operating systems allow a process to keep open files that have no name in a directory. That's fallout from the design of Unix filesystems, where the on-disk data structure that holds permissions and disk blocks of a file's data (the inode) is different from the name and directory location. That's why the system call is `unlink(const char *pathname)` - all that system call does is remove one of possibly many names of a file. If a process has a file open, you didn't delete that file, you just took away its name.

You will have to find the process somehow, and make it exit. It's been a while since I've used Solaris. I know that sometimes Solaris machines had `lsof` installed - you could use that to find the offending process, probably. Solaris has a `/proc` filesystem, but using `/proc` to find open files isn't as easy as it is under Linux. Rebooting will do the trick, but it seems like a drastic measure.

Comment: `fuser` should do the trick, it can help you to find which process is using that/those file pretty quickly.

Comment: @lugiegu has remembered something I forgot. `fuser` is a Solaris program that does different stuff than `lsof`. Give it a try.